# Strange integration

Tags: integration, riemann-surfaces

I would like to compute the following integrations,
$$\int\frac{1}{(p-e)^{2}((p-e)^{2}-p^{2})}dp-\int\frac{1}{p^{2}((p-e)^{2}-p^{2})}dp+\int\frac{1}{(p-e)^{2}p^{2}}dp$$
on one side, mathematica tells me that the result is $\log(-1)$, but on the other side, if I add together the integrands the result seems to be equal $0$.

Can someone please explain what goes wrong?

How could it be that integration over real values can yields an imaginary value?

Also, is it true that this integration can yield multiple different values?

[image]

Comment: As you've noticed, the three integrals' integrands sum to zero, so the antiderivatives are locally constant; which antiderivative you pick is either arbitrary or based on suitably motivated bounds on each integral.

Comment: @J.G. not clear enough, which value would you assign to this integral "0" or "$\log(-1)$?

Comment: _I wouldn't assign a value_, unless I had a specific reason for it. I strongly suggest you edit into your question the context in which you saw a reason to care about this sum of three integrals. I'm guessing it's from a calculation in quantum field theory.

Comment: @J.G. You are very smart to spot correctly that these integrals originated from QFT. However, I am puzzled by your answer. I don't see how the context could affect the value that I should assign for these integrals. How can you add integrands that are not convergent under the same integration sign?!

Comment: To assign a value we need definite integrals, say $\int_Sfdp+\int_Sgdp+\int_Shdp$. Before you jump to $\int_S(f+g+h)dp$, there may be $S$-dependent convergence issues that require us to regularize, renormalize etc. one or more integrals in some careful way. If you wonder _which_ way of manipulating individually divergent integrals is appropriate, we'll need to see more of the original context. See e.g. Sec. II [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555) for how hairy this can get, depending on the specifics.

Comment: Take a case in which we deal with a super-renormalizable theory on a finite phase space for example. In that case, the procedure of renormalization/regularization is irrelevant, and these terms arise when computing some correlation function. The original context will actually not tell anything more than I described in the question.

Comment: There are two options: either _Mathematica_ gave a nonzero answer because of a bug, or it's worth adding context showing that's not the case relevant to your problem.

Comment: Here is the context: we have a scattering process with some external current which is producing particles and I would like to compute the scattering matrix to measure some event. I actually expect this result to be multi-valued as in the case of Log[-1], would you claim that this is not guaranteed to be the case? In other words, is there mathematical justification to add the integrands together even if the integration interval includes branching points?

Comment: That you want to motivate a multi-valued scattering matrix, but are concerned about its complex phase, is **excellent** context to provide in a question. But I suspect any articulation by you of why you expect the matrix is multi-valued, or by an answerer of why _Mathematica_ says it's imaginary, would more readily belong/occur on Physics SE. I don't have the technical knowledge to help at this stage.

Comment: My perspective is different than yours, I think this is just an abstract mathematical question for which the context is irrelevant. I have no idea what I should expect, I can just guess.. the answer should come from the calculation.

Comment: Using Mathematica 13.1, it returns $0$

Comment: It can give multiple values. Look at the condition - it says complex log.

Comment: If you have a problem to see that just compute them one-by-one and then simplify.